# How do I change which radio button is selected using a function?

Tags: javascript, function, radio-button, checked

I have a radio group of 3 choices of which the first is selected by default. I want to make it to where the second one is selected upon clicking another item. This is what I have...

```
function selectSS()
{
    document.getElementById("width").value=16;
    document.getElementById("gauge_1").checked;
}
```

I then use onClick to call the function, the value of width changes to 16 like it is supposed to but how do I get it to select the radion button with the id gauge_1?

Comment: In your code you're just reading the property, not assigning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **set** its `checked` state to `true`, so use:

```
document.getElementById("gauge_1").checked = true;
```

In your code, you're **getting** it and doing nothing with it.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#attr-checked

Comment: No problem :) Since this helped, you might want to accept it as the answer. If you need more help with this stuff, let me know